# What is the mechanism between max_requests and max_requests_jitter in gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn, gevent

According to the official guide

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#settings

a worker will restart when it has handled `max_requests` requests.

But when `max_requests_jitter` is set, a worker will restart when it has handled `randint(0, max_requests_jitter)` request, to stagger worker restarts to avoid all workers restarting at the same time.

Is that means `max_requests_jitter` setting will override `max_requests` and make it be invalid？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#max-requests-jitter) -

> The jitter causes the restart per worker to be randomized by
> `randint(0, max_requests_jitter)`. This is intended to stagger worker
> restarts to avoid all workers restarting at the same time.

What I understand is that the jitter is a random addition to each worker and the term `max_requests_jitter` should be (though not necessary) smaller than `max_requests`.

In other words, worker_1 will restart after `max_requests + j1` requests, worker_2 will restart after `max_requests + j2` requests etc. where the values of `j1, j2, j3...` are determined by the `max_requests_jitter` argument.